# OData v4.0 via ASP.NET WebAPI - Can Excel consume a service?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, wcf-data-services

I have built a few WebAPIs since it was born, including one supporting OData URL filters when that was new. I see now that OData over WebAPI has matured, I see it can serve service metadata.

Is it complete enough for Excel or other OData client tooling to plug and play as if it were a full WCF Data Service (ye olde Astoria)?

That's it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is. In the past you had to do the right configuration or do [a workaround](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/820) to populate the OData feed from Web API correctly, to be able to consume it from Excel. Suprotim Agarwal wrote an excellent [blog post](http://www.devcurry.com/2013/03/getting-started-with-odata-and-aspnet.html) about all the steps necessary to consume the feed from Excel, including creating and configuring the endpoint and what the steps in Excel are.

Comment: Thanks and I also found this blog post on future of OData production on MS stack (i.e. use WebAPI): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/27/future-direction-of-wcf-data-services.aspx

Answer (score 3):

OData V1-3 services can be consumed by the Data tab and Power Pivot data source import of Excel. While Excel's support for importing data from OData V4 services will rely on Power Query. That support is planned targeting early next year according to this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2169958f-9e2a-4fc2-a844-c0dce4c17a19/support-of-odata-v40?forum=powerquery