# web api Odata v4 content negotiation for excel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-core-1.0

Based off [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27375096/odata-v4-0-via-asp-net-webapi-can-excel-consume-a-service), is it possible to setup odata so that when can accept header of '**application/vnd.ms-excel**'is request, the endpoint would return an excel spreadsheet with the power query data source set in the downloaded doc without hard coding every endpoint to check the headers for an accept type?

if not, what is the best way handle the content negotiation to export to excel.

Answer (score 0):

Web API OData only supports `application/json` and `application/atom+xml` out of the box. If you want to support `application/vnd.ms-excel` in your service, you will have to implement a custom `MediaTypeFormatter`. See [How to provide custom mediatype formats for OData Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291547/how-to-provide-custom-mediatype-formats-for-odata-api).